# Compare (Diff) ODB++ Files

Tags: pcb-design, layout, pcb-layers

A few years ago I was making layout changes to a PCB and wanted to be 100% sure that one particular interface did not change at all. My layout contractor generated an ODB++ compare file (I would also call it a diff file) that contained all the layers of the Rev 1 PCB, followed by all the layers of the Rev 2 PCB, followed by a corresponding set of diff layers that highlighted the differences between Rev 1 and Rev 2 on each layer.

Is this a standard trick/ tool for comparing ODB files? If so, is there an existing tool that will compare/ diff ODB files? Either Open Source or licensed. Or is this likely something done with a proprietary in-house script/ tool by the layout contractor?

I'm just curious how they did this.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in [viewmate](https://www.pentalogix.com/t/software-products/viewmate), which has an automatic compare option that allows one to compare two layers. However, this option is only available in the paid version. If not then in the free version two layers can be loaded and compared by visual inspection.

Comment: Yes, I use the ViewMate (free version) to do gerber-to-gerber comparison quite often.  At the end of the day, it's the gerbers that count.

Comment: The paid version (which I don't have, but a tech that works with me has) does this. I was looking at a design yesterday in which they compared layers. They even saved the compared files and I was able to view the differences on my free version, however the diff can only be generated with the paid version.

Comment: When I do the compare in viewmate, I usually just select two layers of the old and new versions for viewing. Then visually inspect the differences, not as clean as a diff ( the compare shows up differences in white) but it saves me from having to buy a paid version of viewmate.

Comment: Finally got around to trying this. I've only tried the free version so far. It seems like the differences between two layers are a little more obvious if you set one to negative.

Comment: You can also set the colors of the layers and turn two of them on, it will make a different color where there are differences